# Java concurrency for periodic database batch insert

Tags: java, database, multithreading

Scenario: One thread is being called up to thousands of times per second to do inserts to the same table and is currently doing them one-by-one.

Goal: Do periodic batch inserts instead to improve performance.

Trying to use a TimerTask to instead add objects being saved to a list as the thread's `saveItem` method gets called, then combine them for a batch insert every 2 seconds or so.

First thought was to have two Lists, call them `toSave` and `toSaveBackup`. When the thread's `saveItem` method is called to save something it will be added to the toSave list, but once the TimerTask kicks off and needs to save everything to the database, it will set an AtomicBoolean flag `saveInProgress` to true.  This flag is checked by `saveItem` and it will add to toSaveBackup instead of toSave if `saveInProgress` is true.  When the batch save is complete, all items will in toSaveBackup will be moved to the toSave list, probably with a synchronized block on the lists.

Is this a reasonable approach?  Or is there a better best practice?  My googling skills have failed me so any help is welcome.

Misc info:

- All these inserts are to the same table
- Inserts are driven by receipt of MQTT messages, so I can't combine them in a batch before this point

**Update:** A tweak on CKing's answer below achieved the desired approach:  A TimerTask runs every 100 ms and checks the size of the `saveQueue` and how long it's been since a batch was saved.  If either of these values exceed the configured limit (save every 2 seconds or every 1000 records etc) then we save. A LinkedBlockingQueue is used to simplify sychronization.

Thanks again to everyone for their help!

Comment: Why not put things into a `BlockingQueue`, set a deadline, and keep calling `take()` (with a timeout) from the "batch insertion" thread until you hit that deadline?

Comment: Well, this is a classic use case for any of the `BlockingQueue` implementations. Also, why `TimerTask`. Why not use a predefined batch size to decide when to insert the batch?

Comment: I meant `poll()`, rather than `take()`. `take()` has no timeout overload.

Comment: I would for size here. As @CKing mentioned. The db performance hits come from size

Comment: @CKing, in checking for size only, we will not insert unless we've got enough, right? So what if producer is stopped before that size is reached? Time check is necessary

Comment: @M.Prokhorov That can be handled as well. Don't need a timer task for it.

Comment: @CKing, meaning? If it's not TimerTask or scheduled task, how do we check for time?

Comment: @AndyTurner Ahhh I never read up on BlockingQueues, that is exactly what I need.

Comment: @CKing The data in the table we're inserting too might be consumed as often as every 5~30 seconds, so even if we're only receiving a handful of inserts it's still important that they be in the database.  If not with a TimerTask, what's the best approach?

Comment: @Matthew You did not mention anything about wanting to consume the data from the database as soon as possible. That changes things and timely inserts would indeed be necessary.

Comment: @CKing Sorry for not not mentioning that! In that scenario is a TimerTask a reasonable approach? The data might also only be consumed every half hour but the goal of this task is to help performance when there is a high rate of inserts and doing them all individually is costly.

Comment: @Matthew Yes. If timely inserts is an objective, someone needs to regularly take whatever data is available at that instance and insert it into the DB. That someone can be the `TimerTask`.

Comment: @Matthew, I feel like with using BlockingQueue (unbounded or not depends on whether or not you want inserters to block and wait until previous insert is done) and TimerTask you will almost get what you want. Do note though, that your data after this change will occasionally become stale by however much time passed between previous insert and current read, so potentially someone might observe "previous" state instead of current one.

Comment: If you are consuming the data so quickly, why do you need a table in between? Have a queue and then the workers consume them. Keep the object until is has been consumed (message )then discard. It seems a lot of i/o and indirection going in and a lot going out.

Comment: @CKing Excellent. If you want to put a bow on that and post it as an answer to this question I'll accept it.  Having an accepted answer to the question will help me find it when I inevitably run into this again in a few months.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  That is very true, the system is highly configurable so I think they key is just making sure that the data is consumed much more often that the period of the batch insert.  Thank you for your note on bounded and unbounded, this is the first time I've needed a BlockingQueue and they seem extremely useful.

Comment: @efekctive That's a great observation.  There are several different use cases, some where historic data is needed and inserts from weeks ago will be read and some where we need what we inserted 10 seconds ago.  There is some caching going on to prevent too much superfluous reading and the database is used to keep data until we know we're done with it.

Comment: Also what is your latency? If the latency is big enough during inserts the tasks will trip over each other

Comment: @Matthew I provided a basic structure that you can use to implement your solution. You may use different APIs all together to implement your solution but the approach would be somewhat similar. Take a look and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your primary objective is to wait for a predefined amount of time  and then trigger an insert. When an insert is in progress, you wan't other insert requests to wait till the insert is complete. After the insert is complete, you want to repeat the same process again for the next insert requests.

I would propose the following solution with the above understanding in mind. You don't need to have two separate lists to achieve your goal. Also note that I am proposing an old fashioned solution for the sake of explanation. I cover some other APIs you can use at the end of my explanation. Here goes :

1. Define a `Timer` and a `TimerTask` that will run every N seconds.
2. Define an `ArrayList` that will be used for queuing up insert requests sent to `saveItem` method.
3. The `saveItem` method can define a `sycnrhonized` block around this `ArrayList`. You can add items to the `ArrayList` within this `synchronized` block as and when `saveItem` is called.
4. On the other side of the equation, `TimerTask` should have a `synchronized` block on the same `ArrayList` as well inside its `run` method. It should insert all the records present in the `ArrayList` at that given moment into the database. Once the insert is complete, the `TimerTask` should `clear` the `ArrayList` and finally come out of the `synchronized` block.

You will no longer need to explicitly monitor if an insert is in progress or create a copy of your `ArrayList` when an insert is in progress. Your `ArrayList` becomes the shared resource in this case.

If you also want `size` to be a deciding factor for proceeding with inserts,  you can do this :

1. Define an int called `waitAttempts` in `TimerTask`. This field indicates the number of consecutive wake ups for which the `TimerTask` should do nothing if the `size` of the `list` is not big enough.
2. Everytime the `TimerTask` wakes up, it can do something like `if(waitAttempts%3==0 || list.size > 10) { insert data } else { increment waitAttempts and do nothing. Exit the synchronized block and the run method }`. You can change `3` and `10` to whatever number suits your throughput requirements.

**Note** Intrinsic locking was used as a means of explaining the approach. One can always take this approach and implement it using modern constructs such as a `BlockingQueue` that would eliminate the need to `synchronize` manually on the `ArrayList`. I would also recommend the use of `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` instead of a `TimerTask` as it ensures that there will only be one thread running at any given time and there wont be an overlap of threads. Also, the logic for `waitAttempts` is indicative and will need to be adjusted to work correctly.

Comment: Wonderful answer but not quite the `size` deciding factor I intended.  Instead of "Only write when you have X elements, check every Y seconds" I was going to "Write every Y seconds or as soon as you get X elements".  In this case the TimerTask could just run more often and check both the time and size criteria, correct?  Sorry again for my ambiguity!

Comment: Apologies for assuming, your first comment about batch sizes on the original question gave me the impression you understood.  Two consumers seems like a very awkward approach, especially if you don't want to save multiple copies of the same data.  I'll update my original question with the approach that I took  that works.

Thank you for your help, answer accepted.

Comment: @Matthew I recommended two consumers because your question said *every 2 seconds*. If `TimerTask` is sleeping when you have reached your optimum batch size, you will have to wait for your timer to wake up to complete the insert. 2 seconds felt like a lot of time to waste when you are expecting data to be read every 5 seconds (based on your comment). I only just found out about your 100ms `TimerTask` from your latest edit. That makes 2 consumers look pointless :). That said, multiple copies of the same data will never happen since you synchronize on the same resource.

Comment: That makes sense.  I didn't want to make a wall of text that no one would read and I left out a lot of relevant details.  I'll try to include all the relevant info next time.

Oh sweet, I didn't realize I had enough reputation to vote on answers now.  I had 11 for forever and now I have enough.  Have an upvote and thank you again!